# C++ error while adding values to map in .h

Tags: c++, stl

I have a .h file in which I have created a dictionary as follows :-

```
map < char, string > mydictionary;
```

I go on to populate the values as :-

```
string t = "test";
mydictionary['a'] = "asdf";
mydictionary['b'] = t;
```

When I try to build the project I get errors for the two lines above mentioning `C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations`. Unfortunately I find the error message quite cryptic and am not sure about how to approach/solve it.

Why does this error happen? How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Please post your real code and the entire exact error.

Comment: I'm sorry thats a copy paste error, @JoachimPileborg

Comment: Where are `mydictionary['a'] = "asdf"; mydictionary['b'] = t;` the  placed? Inside a function or outside?

Comment: @KirilKirov In a .h file, outside all functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put statements at global scope; statements can only go in functions. (Note that this is different from variable initializers, which can go in global scope).

You will need to initialize the map in a function, or, (in C++11), use an initializer list:

```
map < char, string > mydictionary {{'a', "asdf"}, {'b', t}};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have these

```
mydictionary['a'] = "asdf";
mydictionary['b'] = t;
```

outside a function. You need to move them inside a function (in `main` or in some other and call it).

Anything different from definition or declaration must be placed inside a function.